# Infinite loop when adding new element to an array React

Tags: reactjs

**The problem is the following:**

when I receive `props` from `parent component` with the `data` of a `new element`, A new card must be added, but instead of it, the code starts to add this card an `infinite number of times`.

How to fix this? Code is below

```
const fetchCards = () => {
  return Axios(apiOptions('GET')).then(
    response => response.data,
    error => {
      console.log(`[Error]: ${error}`);
    }
  );
};
const addCard = props => {
  return Axios(apiOptions('POST', props))
    .then(result => result.data)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
const PlacesList = props => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCards().then(res => setCards(res))
  }, []);

// Problem with this part 

  if (props.newCard.titleValue !== undefined) {
      console.log(props.newCard.titleValue);
      addCard(props.newCard).then(res => setCards(cards.concat(res)));
    }


const createCards = () => {
    return cards
      .map((card, id) => {
        if (id > cards.length - 10) {
          return (
            <PlaceCard
              title={card.name}
              url={card.link}
            />
          );
        }
        return false;
      })
      .reverse();
  };

  return <div className="places-list root__section">{createCards()}</div>;
};
export default PlacesList;
```

Simplified example [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-tree-e9di4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: sandbox, please.

Comment: @PiotrŻak added

Comment: Ok - i slept - but you see, automatically another person solve your ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: The answer below are based on the codesandbox you gave and not the snippet you provided:

**To answer what causes the issue is:**

```
    if (props.newItem) {
      setItems(items.concat([10]));
    }
```

this code chunk is being rendered on the component root and not inside of any `useEffect` or callback function. Every "render" of the component will call the `setItems` and since any state change (these are triggered by `setState` or the second result on `useState`) will cause a re-render on the component, what will happen is it will re-render infinitely.

---

**To answer your problem:**

on your List component, add this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.newItem) {
      setItems(items.concat([10]));
    }
  }, [props.newItem]);`
```

This will only take effect if the value of `props.newItem` was updated.

But this is will not work when you click the button again since the value of `newItems` is always `true`.

To fix that, add setNewItem when calling List (i.e):

```
<List newItem={newItem} setNewItem={setNewItem} />
```

This will pass give your List component the ability to change the item value. so let's add this to your useEffect on the second code chunk above like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.newItem) {
      setItems(items.concat([10]));
      props.setNewItem(false);
    }
  }, [props.newItem]);`
```

we set it to false so it will always toggle the value of `newItem` and will always add a new item on your list.